# Can't add a button to the hubpage Template

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

how is it possible to add a button or another visual style element to only one hubsection of the default hubpage template in Windows Phone 8.1?

I would like to add a refresh button above my ListView.

```
        <Hub x:Name="Hub" x:Uid="Hub" Header="BuLi Tweet" Foreground="White" Background="{StaticResource RasenHintergrund}">

        <HubSection x:Uid="HubSection1" Header="Aktueller Spieltag" Width="400"
                    DataContext="{Binding Groups[0]}" HeaderTemplate="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderTemplate}">
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListView
                    ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True">
                    <GridView                
                    Margin="5,0,0,0"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
                    AutomationProperties.Name="Items In Group"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MatchIcon}"
                    SelectionMode="None"
                    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
                    ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick"
                    ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True">
                        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </GridView.ItemsPanel>  
                    </GridView>
                </ListView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
```

Comment: Add button and set visibility using converter(if it is first item then set visibility to visible) or you can use template selector

Comment: @Archana thanks, I see where you want to go with this... not sure if I can figure this one out... Do you have a little code snippet to help out?

Comment: I think template selector is not required in this. Please see my answer. Let me know if i am wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you want button inside first hub section before listview. Just add grid and define RowDefinations for Grid

```
        <HubSection x:Uid="HubSection1" Header="Aktueller Spieltag" Width="400"
                    DataContext="{Binding Groups[0]}" HeaderTemplate="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderTemplate}">
            <DataTemplate> 
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Button Content="Refresh" Visibility="{Binding}"/>
                    <ListView Grid.Row="1"
               ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True">
                    <GridView                
                    Margin="5,0,0,0"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
                    AutomationProperties.Name="Items In Group"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MatchIcon}"
                    SelectionMode="None"
                    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
                    ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick"
                    ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True">
                        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </GridView.ItemsPanel>  
                    </GridView>
                </ListView>
</Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
```

Comment: My apologies, for asking this question.... was sitting too long in front of it. stupid! 
Thank You a lot, this was exactly what i want to achieve.